# Having a set of classes and accessing their methods and properties

Tags: java

I have a Selenium Webdriver automated testing project and I have structured it this way:

there are two classes that are the actual tests
there is one class that reads generates test data and defines some custom methods that I use
and there are 3 "service" classes - email sender, screenshot capturer and csv reader.

Now, I would have liked it if I was able to just use the methods and properties from all the classes in the project (or maybe I can but I dont know how) without having to ridiculously extend in this circular fashion

So what I am doing now is the following

Test1, Test2 extend AppData which extends Mailer which extends ScreenCapturer which extends CSV reader.

Im sure there is a more elegant way of doing this, but what is it?

PS: Do you think its a good idea that I put all the services in one class and just extend this one class, and if you do - why?

EDIT: I got a pretty good answer on this question, so Im removing the first instance of code that I had placed here, because now my question has changed slightly.

EDIT: Okay, Im trying this new stuff now and this is what bothers me.

I have this AppData class that contains a method randomizer(int min, int max):

```
public abstract class AppData { 
    public int randomizer(int min, int max) {
        int d = (max - min) + 1;
        int c = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((d)));
        return c;
    }

}
```

and in another class - AppTest, I want to use randomizer:

```
public class AppTest { //extends AppData 
      private AppData appdata;

    public void someVoid() {

            int randomNumber = appdata.randomizer(1, 99999);
            int randomUser = appdata.randomizer(1, 250); 
            int randomPlace = appdata.randomizer(1, 65);
    }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Should I put "appdata." before each time I mention randomizer?
I had to remove the "static" modifier from the randomizer method, before I was able to call it at all.
I use this method A LOT. And does the same practice apply for variables?

and then I have to use this set of 15 custom methods, it seems inconvenient to always put "appdata." everywhere. Im sure Im not doing this right.

```
        focus();
        fillByName("user[first_name]", firstUserFirstName);
        fillByName("user[last_name]", firstUserLastName + randomNumber);
        fillByName("user[email]", firstUsersEmail);
        fillByName("user[password]", password);
        submitByName("user[password]");
```

Comment: Seeing the code is easier for us to understand it than reading a vague description of it. Post the code, and tell us what you want to achieve. "use the methods and properties from all the classes" doesn't mean anything to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is (maybe) `Dependency Injection`. Don't make a chain of inheritanced classes but inject "Service" Classes if needed. P.e. in the constructor of `AppTest3` inject `AppData`.

You may need `Factories` to create your classes (with all the injected dependencies).

```
public class Mailer {
    public void sendMailWithAttachment(
        String attachment
    ) {
        //code here
    }
}

public class AppTest3 {
    private Mailer mailer;
    public AppTest3 (
        Mailer mailer
    ) {
       this.mailer = mailer;
    }
    public void run() {
        // do some crazy things here and
        this.mailer.sendMailWithAttachment(
            "crazy file content"
        );
    }
}

public class AppTest3Factory {
    public AppTest3 createAppTest3() {
       return new AppTest3(
          new Mailer();
       );
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(
        String [] args
    ) {
        AppTest3Factory appFactory = new AppTest3Factory();
        AppTest3 app = appFactory.createAppTest3();
        app.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read about Dependency Injection, but I cant understand how to apply that to my case? @Frank Olschewski

Comment: I do not realy understand what you are trying to do with your given classes and how they need each other. I edited my answer to show you how to use Dependency Injection and Factories.

Comment: I've edited my question with a real life example, I just need you to confirm that Im doing it right? Thanks!

Comment: If your AppTest is a Unit Test there is nothing wrong to instantiate AppData in the @Before annotated function. --- I think it's not a good idea to change the question completely and add new questions to the existing one. You should ask your question regarding the DataProvider in a new question. I'm not experienced in using the DataProvider, therefore I will not answer.

Comment: Yes, I created a new question. How about the other two answers, regarding the matter of subject of this question (the ones above the dataProvider one)? Can you confirm that this is the way Its done?

Comment: If `AppTest` is a Unit Test you can to this: `private AppData appdata = new AppData();` or `@Before public void setUp() { this.appdata = new AppData(); }`. If `AppTest` ist not a Unit Test, inject `AppData` in the constructor of `AppTest`.

Comment: is this related to the "randomizer" question and always appending "appdata." before use of every AppData method? I dont get it.

Comment: You can create `AppData` one time and use the function `randomizer` multiple times.

Comment: but my question is do I always have to append "appdata." to "randomizer" in order to use it? "appdata.randomizer"?

Comment: You ask me how to use the function `randomizer` of the Class `AppData` with a property of the name `appdata` in the current class. `this.appdata.randomizer(1, 99999);`. You made it right in your example. `AppData` is not a parent of the Class `AppTest` anymore, therefore you have to access it by the property `appdata`.

Comment: well, after all this I think inheritance is better than dependency injection? It requires much less thought and typing. Or is there something Im missing here?

Comment: Dependency Injection is essential important to make your classes testable. But this is not the place to discuss this. Think of Dependendy Injection as a modern programming paradigm all cool guys use.